# Loop through multiple field names

Tags: php, html, if-statement, file-upload

I've got the following input fields:

```
<input name="file1" type="file">
<input name="file2" type="file">
<input name="files[]" type="file" multiple>
```

I'm trying to figure out the best way to check which of the fields above are not empty and perform some DB action with the ones that have files in them.

I can check them each one manually like this but I am wondering if there is a better way to do this:

```
if(!empty($_FILES['file1']['name']) {
    // Perform checks/etc for file1
}

if(!empty($_FILES['file2']['name']) {
    // Perform checks/etc for file2
}

if(!empty($_FILES['files']['name'][0]) {
    // Loop the array, perform checks/etc for each one
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "best" and "better"? Is there an objective measure that you have in mind that can quantify this? Questions generating primarily opinion based answers are generally frowned upon at StackOverflow which is why I'm asking.

Comment: @LouisLangholtz I am trying to make it as neatly as possible. So basically less lines, cleaner code and not repeat a lot of the same code over and over again. Something like OOP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will loop through all the files and tell you which ones are empty, and put the files that have content in the $submittedFiles array.

```
$submittedFiles = [];
foreach ($_FILES as $n => $f) {
        if (!empty($f['name']) && !empty($f['name'][0])) {
                $submittedFiles[] = $f;
        } else {
                echo $n.' is empty';
        }
} 
var_dump($submittedFiles);
```

Comment: The thing is the first 2 files are not multiples so they've got a single file each and then the last one got multiple option available.